# HTTP/3 and its impact

Tags: quic, http3

Recently Chrome, Firefox, cURL etc announced their support for HTTP/3 (it was earlier termed as HTTP-over-QUIC).

How do you see its adaptation impact from perspective of changes in:

1. Applications (web-based, mobile, pure socket based etc)
2. Hosting infrastructures (web/app servers, firewalls, loadbalancers, CDNs, router, switches etc) & ISPs etc.
3. Security (new threats, vulnerabilities, landscape of VAPT tools etc.)
4. Congestion-control

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A very subjective question so not sure a great fit for here but here’s my two cents:

1. Shouldn’t make any further difference behind what HTTP/2 did. It closes one edge-case of that (lost packets can make HTTP/2 slower on HTTP/2 than HTTP/1.1) and also potentially brings some performance improvements to the initial connection setup. If you’ve not move to, or optimised for, HTTP/2 then may wish to consider that in preparation. Priorities are also due to get a rethink in HTTP/3 but not decided how yet. At the end of the day it’s a transport layer change and the basic semantics of HTTP/2 doesn’t change so to higher level apps it should be fairly seamless - like HTTP/2 was mostly to HTTP/1.1 users.
2. It’s UDP based (with fallback to TCP-based HTTP/2 and/or HTTP/1.1) which will be fun to enable and setup! Also [TLS libraries need to change to support it](https://daniel.haxx.se/blog/2019/01/21/quic-and-missing-apis/) so could be a while before we see it in some servers. CDNs are already leading the way and will be easiest way of getting this. Like HTTP/2, it’s probably most important to have it on your edge server and then down grade to HTTP/2 or even HTTP/1.1 for internal traffic beyond that. It’s also more fully encrypted which will make it difficult to sniff and reroute traffic as less information is readable to middle boxes than was in TCP.
3. See answer 2 above which will make it more difficult to sniff traffic. Also it’s **very new** (not even fully finished and approved at this time of writing) so there may be implementation bugs like there were for HTTP/2 ([for example](https://blog.cloudflare.com/on-the-recent-http-2-dos-attacks/)), and some products will not support it initially. On plus side it’s only available over HTTPS which is good for security.

Answer (score -1):

HTTP/3 is built on top of QUIC. It comes with many features.

1. **Built-in mandatory encryption:** Encryption is a part of the QUIC protocol so it is mandatory. On HTTP/2 and TCP, encryption was done with TLS which encrypts only Application Layer Data so that has some security vulnerability and it also requires extra roundtrip. But on QUIC, the transport layer data is encrypted and no extry roundtrip is required.
2. **Drops support for vulnerable encrypting Algorithm**: It uses TLS 1.3 which drops support for vulnerable encrypting algorithms used in TLS 1.2.
3. **Zero Roundtrip time for existing TLS connections:** The TLS keys are stored in a Cache so once a TLS connection is initiated, the later connections with that server don't need any Roundtrip.
4. Removal of the head-of-line blocking issue on the Transport Layer: This is another feature of QUIC.
5. **Connection Migration:** That is when a connection is established, the client can change its Address. For example, this happens when a user goes from Wifi to Cellular data and Vice-Versa.